# Troubles interacting with an element using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've been facing a persistent issue while using Selenium in Python to interact with a specific element on a webpage. I consistently encounter the "element not interactable" error, and sometimes nothing is printed at all, and despite trying various solutions, I haven't been able to resolve it.

The HTML of the input field is as follows:

```
<input class="bubble-element Input cmaUqaF a1706808252806x2093" type="email" placeholder="" style="background-color: var(--color_OB013_default);" xpath="1">
```

And here is the part of the Python code responsible for interacting with the element:

```
email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@type, "email")]'))
)

email_input.send_keys("email@example.com")
```

This is the direct XPATH: `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/input`

**What I've Tried:**

- I have tried using different wait conditions such as `element_to_be_clickable`, `visibility_of_element_located`, `presence_of_element_located`, and `element_to_be_selected` to ensure the element is ready for interaction.
- I have attempted different XPath expressions, including direct XPaths and using contains to match the type attribute.
- I've used execute_script to scroll the element into view before attempting to interact with it.
- I've ensured that the page content is stable before attempting interactions, adding explicit waits where necessary.

Example of the error i get:

```
Error during registration: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.86)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF693015E42+3538674]
```

**Note:** I made sure the element is not within an `iframe`

Sreenshots from selectorshub:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** I've been able to bypass that using `pyautogui` by automating the keyboard but it sounds like a dumb solution to me.

Comment: Able to provide the url?

Comment: [link](https://undetectable.ai/login) Then click on Sign Up at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was continuously getting the same error, and while I couldn't explain why, I was able to solve the issue by using XPath. It looks like you tried XPath too, but I think your XPath is wrong.

XPath usage should generally be avoided since any changes to the websites structure will break your usage of XPath, but if you can deal with that and just replace the XPath in the future, this module works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

def click_element_by_xpath(url, xpath, email):
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

    try:
        driver.get(url)
        sign_up_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "LoginPageSignUpSwitch"))
        )
        sign_up_button.click()

        element_to_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
        )

        element_to_click.click()
        element_to_click.send_keys(email)
        print("input email.")
        time.sleep(5)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"error: {e}")

    finally:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    URL = "https://undetectable.ai/login"
    XPATH = "/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/input"
    email = "fakemail@email.com"
    click_element_by_xpath(URL, XPATH, email)
```

EDIT:
Since your XPath was the issue, here is how I retrieved the XPath:

[image]

Notice where my mouse is hovering; I then go to Copy->Copy full XPath

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I have two questions; 1. I opened the developer tools and selected the email input and copied its XPATH, why was it wrong? 2. What do you recommend doing so that i can avoid updating my script every time due to the dynamic changes of the website?

Comment: @Boundless For Q1, I'm not sure what to say other than Inspecting, clicking on the element in the html code, right-clicking and clicking "copy full x-path". If you are unable how do that and get the X-path that I got, I can edit and attach a video to my answer. For Q2, you should typically identify by a class or type or anything but x-path, since those change less frequently (often never), but I was getting errors when doing that for some reason

Comment: That's what I did, I copied the full xpath and I still get this one: `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/input` for some reason

Comment: ill add a video